# Getting a null pointer exception while running junit

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I am running my test case and I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.cleanup(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:177)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
```

Here's my unit test:

```
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.junit.Test;
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-context.xml"})

public class MyTest {  
    @Test    
    public void testMyTest() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

I am using mvn test to run this test and I am getting this exception. I think it has to do with the @ annotations but I am not sure why.

Comment: Shouldn't your test class have a method annotated as `@Test`?

Comment: Yes it should..I might have deleted it here while formatting this code. But that's not what's causing the exception.

Comment: Well, no.  It's something to do with your context file.  Are you sure that it's getting read in correctly?  Do you need to have any other pieces of your context on your classpath when you run that file?

Comment: Nope, that's the only piece I need.

Comment: You can annotate a class with `@Test`? Doesn't this belong the test method? ([JavaDoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html))

Comment: @Tom, its a mistake. Fixed it. But that doesn't fix the problem. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: I'm going to say that this looks like a bug in the Camel-Spring integration library. Any problem with the context definition should be either throwing a domain exception (such as bean creation) or throwing an NPE right next to user code. That's so far into the framework call stack that I tend to think the OP is not at fault. Recommend setting a breakpoint on the method mentioned and debugging the NPE up as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your path to your spring-context.xml is correct and that the file 
meta-inf/spring/spring-context.xml is present where it is supposed to be?

Try taking out all of the annotations and adding them one at a time to determine exactly what the problem is.